# How can I set Style text from attribute in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers

I have a feature layer in my application.

```
    let layer = new OlLayerVector({
        source: vectorSource
    });
```

So I need to set a style for this `layer`. But style should write attribute value as text.

```
    let layer = new OlLayerVector({
        source: vectorSource
    });

    styles = new Style({
        image:  new Circle({
              radius: 5,
              fill: null,
               stroke: new Stroke({color: 'red', width: 1})
            }),
        text:  new Text({
            text: // this comes from attribute.
        })
    });
```

This `text` will come from attribute value. Can I use formatted style `text` like `"${name}"` ?

(If I use style function, this function called for every feature. For example if I have 1000 features, createStyleFunction called 1000 times.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other option than using a style/labeling function to label each feature individually.

Even if there would be a syntax as suggested by you, internally a function would be called for every single feature.

See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-labels.html for examples.